# change environment variable in child process - bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Hi I have following example. a.sh script sets environment variable which I can see in b.sh (child) script, but if I change it I still have the old value in a.sh

a.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export A=1
./b.sh
echo parent $A
```

b.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo child $A
A=2
export A
echo child $A
```

test:

```
bash-3.00$ ./a.sh
child 1

child 2

parent 1

child 1

child 2
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow to change environment variables from child process?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `a.sh` do `source b.sh` instead of `./b.sh`

`a.sh` should look like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
export A=1
source b.sh
echo parent "$A"
```

Comment: this worked for me, thanks. But what if I need to run b.sh in background?

Comment: You cannot run it in the background, because `source` is actually a shell statement which tells the shell to simply execute all commands in the file as if typed in "manually".

Comment: Running it in the background would be *impossible*. The parent script could reach line 3 before the child script `b.sh` even starts. One of the reasons why line 3 would print the wrong value is that `a.sh` can't predict the future.

Comment: What if `wait` is used?

Comment: this is not from a child process, so technically it does not answer the Question.