# Shell command - How to run?

Tags: json, bash, shell

When I put a command on terminal, it works just fine, but when I put the same command in a .sh script and then run it, it doesn't give any output. What might be the reason for this?

The command:

```
IFS=$'\t'; while read -r k v; do 
    export "$k=\"$v\""
```

Comment: `When I put the exact command in a .sh script` : Do you have a shebang for the script or are you just `sourcing` it? Please read [\[ this \]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496702/can-a-shell-script-set-environment-variables-of-the-calling-shell).

Comment: You have edited out some of the code so that this is no longer valid Bash. The actual code is still available from the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48439370/revisions).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217064/change-environment-variable-in-child-process-bash

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of expected since `export` sets the environment variable for that particular shell.

Docs -

> export command is used to export a variable or function to the
>   environment of all the child processes running in the current shell.
>   export -f functionname # exports a function in the current shell. It
>   exports a variable or function with a value.

So when you create a `sh` script it runs the specified commands into a different shell which terminates once the script exits.

It works with the `sh` script too -

***data.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\t'; while read -r k v; do 
    export "$k=\"$v\""
    echo $HELLO1
    echo $SAMPLEKEY
done < <(jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | [(.key|ascii_upcase), .value] | @tsv' data.json)
```

Output -

```
$ ./data.sh
"world1"

"world1"
"samplevalue"
```

Which suggests that your variables are getting exported but for that particular shell env.

In case you want to make them persistent, try putting scripts or exporting them via `~/.bashrc` OR `~/.profile`.

Once you put them in `~/.bashrc` OR `~/.profile`, you will find the output something as below -

I used `~/.bash_profile` on my MAC OS  -

```
Last login: Thu Jan 25 15:15:42 on ttys006
"world1"

"world1"
"samplevalue"
viveky4d4v@020:~$ echo $SAMPLEKEY
"samplevalue"
viveky4d4v@020:~$ echo $HELLO1
"world1"
viveky4d4v@020:~$
```

Which clarifies that your env variables will get exported whenever you open a new shell, the logic for this lies in `.bashrc` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work)

Put your script as it is `~/.bashrc` at the end -

```
IFS=$'\t'; while read -r k v; do 
    export "$k=\"$v\""
    echo $HELLO1
    echo $SAMPLEKEY
done < <(jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | [(.key|ascii_upcase), .value] | @tsv' data.json)
```

You need to make sure that `data.json` stays in user's home directory.

Comment: then how do I export them since I need to access them from outside as environment variables?

Comment: Try putting them in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: how to put them in `~/.bashrc` from inside the script itself?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: `Put your script as it is ~/.bashrc at the end`. What does this mean? Add `~/.bashrc` at the end of the command?

Comment: This means append your script at the end of `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163857/discussion-between-vivekyad4v-and-qirohchan).

Answer (score 0):

Basically: A child process can't change the [environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) of it's parent process.

You need to source the script instead of executing it:

```
source your_script.sh
```

`source` runs the script in the *current* shell which makes it possible to modify the environment.

---

Alternatively you can create a function in your shell startup files (e.g. ~/.bashrc):

```
my_function() {
    IFS=$'\t'; while read -r k v; do 
        export "$k=\"$v\""
    done < <(jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | [(.key|ascii_upcase), .value] | @tsv' /path/to/data.json)
}
```

After you've started a new shell you can run

```
my_function
```